# Ignore stopwords in MySQL Full-Text Search (IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am using Full-Text Search in MySQL InnoDB table. I am searching using Boolean Full-Text Search (IN BOOLEAN MODE) but my search contains stopwords so it returns no data even if data is available. Here is example of my query

```
SELECT * FROM tablename where match(`desc`) against('+be +belong*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

my table have 2 data which contains `be belongs` and `be belonging` but query still return no data

---

**Some Solutions that I've tried from online sources:**

```
SET @@SESSION.innodb_ft_enable_stopword = 'OFF'; //This still returns no data
```

---

```
SET global ft_stopword_file = '';  //read only variable error
```

---

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_ft_min_token_size = 0;
```

Comment: Check `innodb_ft_min_token_size` variable value. If you need to adjust its value then you'd rebuild FT index.